# Insufficient Privilege Error - Is security checked before logic execution?

Tags: apex, security

While creating an object with picklist value X, there is an afterinsert trigger which runs on the master object and updates  field if picklist value is Z.

user has only read access to master object

even if picklist values!= Z , new record is not getting saved and 'insufficient Privilege ' Error is thrown .

The master record selected from lookup is created by a different user.

But , if I create a master record by our user and then select it in the lookup of detail object , and select picklist!=Z , then no error is thrown .

Is the security checked even before executing the logic ?

Comment: security is checked when we try to update the data. Also if you share the code it will us to help you.

Comment: Share the code, otherwise it's to hard to difficult to help you.